# Using DBOutputFormat in Hadoop

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

When using **DBOutputFormat** with hadoop, say the final result is to go to MySql database. Will Hadoop create separate connection each time a result has to be written? (Would DB be burdened with **too many open connections**). I have not used the format, so any suggestion on the same is acceptable. Would it have a performance upperhand over **Sqoop**? Sqoop can also be used to export output file to DB. Please share your views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an explanation I found [this](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/) blog post from Cloudera:

> The DBOutputFormat writes to the database by generating a set of
>   INSERT statements in each reducer. The reducer’s close() method then
>   executes them in a bulk transaction. Performing a large number of
>   these from several reduce tasks concurrently can swamp a database. If
>   you want to export a very large volume of data, you may be better off
>   generating the INSERT statements into a text file, and then using a
>   bulk data import tool provided by your database to do the database
>   import.

So it appears that each individual reducer will only open one connection, so the database probably won't have too many open connections, but it still could cause performance issues. I don't know for sure, but Sqoop is probably slightly more efficient and robust.

Comment: Sqoop2 is in incubator. Find it quite helpful.